# How to convert a PDF image or an image to text using Tesseract and/or Poppler?

Tags: python, pdf, tesseract, poppler, pdf-extraction

Python 3.6.1 Mac OSX

Regarding Tesseract, I have tried so many different sample/template codes I have found online for PDF -> Text and Image -> Text. None of them seem to work.

**Please let me know if you know of a code that works or a website with a good tutorial for either Tesseract, Poppler, or both.**

Pytesser seems outdated. Magick seems to be a windows only program. Wand does not seem to help either.

**Tesseract-OCR is what I am trying to use** *but I have no idea how to set up a code for it and cannot find a good tutorial that works*. I can only find install tutorials.

**I can use Poppler for PDF->Text**, *but have come across PDF images that I need to extract*. I assume I need a separate code for taking the PDF and turning it into an image file and then a code for turning the image to a text file (Teseseract). **Or I could use Poppler's PDFImage, which I do not know how to code for (help here would be very much appreciated as well).**

My code for Poppler PDF to Text is:

```
import csv, re, requests, subprocess, sys

url = (
    'http://gwinnetttaxcommissioner.publicaccessnow.com/'
    'Portals/0/PDF/Excess%20funds%20all%20years%20-%20rev02232017.pdf'
)

r = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

filename = url.split('/')[-1].replace('%20', ' ')
with open(filename, 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(r.content)

subprocess.call(['pdftotext', '-layout', filename])

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
with open(filename[:-3] + 'txt') as fh:
    text = fh.read()
    for line in re.findall('(?m)^\d.+\d$', text):
        writer.writerow(re.split(r' {3,}', line))
```

And it works great.

**I cannot figure out how to format Poppler's PDFImage though.**

**Additionally, how would I implement something like this in Tesseract, since it is one of the best OCRs?**

Comment: @Tienkamp thank you, it has to be automated through Python. I will look into the options your shared after work, but do you know how to work Poppler's PDFImage or Tesseract in Python?

Comment: Thanks @Tienkamp I saw that one and tried https://pastebin.com/8sFdgStm but could not figure out where to place the image file/URL?? It does not work when placed in URL.

Comment: @Tienkamp I figured out I just need to call the url as a function. Can you possibly help me solve my new question regarding the seemingly unlikely error that was brought up in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267807/typeerror-initial-value-must-be-str-or-none-not-bytes-during-pytesseract-con ? Thanks a bunch.